# JS not working on click of an asp:Button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json, onclick

I have an array in JS and I am using following function to send it to aspx page

```
var array = [] //I want this array to be sent with JSON.
function result()
{
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ list: array });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.aspx",
        data: jsonText,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () { alert("it worked"); },
        failure: function () { alert("Uh oh"); }
    });

}
```

And I am calling it on click of a button in asp, like this:

```
<asp:Button id="submitbtn" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="result()" />
```

But it isn't working. So, whats the exact way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code it will work for you

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="demotest.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web.demotest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var array =[[48.154176701412744,11.551694869995117],[48.15131361676726,11.551694869995117],[48.15555092529958,11.549291610717773]]
    function result() {
        var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ list: array });
        $.ajax({
            url: "demotest.aspx/Demo", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: jsonText,
            success: function (data) { alert("it worked"); },
            error: function () { alert("Uh oh"); }
        });
        return false;
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Button id="submitbtn" runat="server" Text="Ajax Call"  OnClientClick="javascript:return result();" /> 
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Write below code in C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Web
{
    public partial class demotest : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static void Demo(double[][] list)
        {
            //Write code here
        }
    }
}
```

**For datatype use in c#.Please see the below picture**
[image]

Comment: It doesn't work. Don't you think I need to have a method in my asp code that will accept array? Lets say that method's name is arrayAccept and we making the ajax url as, url: "test.aspx/arrayAccept".

Comment: I have updated the answer please try above answer.it will work for you

Comment: Perfect, thats what I was talking about. But it isn't accepting the values of array outside this function it only works for array defined with in it. How to make call to that array which I have defined outside this function?

Comment: My array name is "array" and I am assigning it to JSON as "var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ list: array });" but, it doesn't work.

Comment: I have and it works. But it fails when I try to pass the a global array to it. i.e. "list: window.array" or simply, "list: array". And I want it to accept that array as well.

Comment: Ok! I'll update my question by adding that array. Just check it out.

Comment: I have seen. You want to pass global array  as parameter.It will work fine no issue is there.Please see updated answer.

Comment: Yup its working. But I don't know why it's not accepting my array. Anyway, Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just changed public static void Demo(string[] list)
        {
            //Write code here
        } to    public static void Demo(double[] list)
    {
        //Write code here
    }

Comment: My array is having following data in it (48.154176701412744,11.551694869995117),(48.15131361676726,11.551694869995117),(48.15555092529958,11.549291610717773)
so what will be the appropriate data type to get access to this array? Like will this method be like : public static void Demo(string[] list), as it gives error on as shown above and when I try to access it like void Demo(double[] list), it gives me an array as [0 0 0 0].